# General relations between sums of projector matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wish to know is there any general relationship between the two matrices :
\begin{equation}
M_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iP_i
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
M_n=M_1^n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^nP_i\;.
\end{equation}
For example I initially thought that $M_1$ and $M_n$ had to be a multiple of one another. However I realised this is not true in general. I realise this is possibly not the best way of asking this question, but any sort of relationship might be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that it is only true that $M_n = M_1^n$ if we are given that $P_i P_j = 0$ for all pairs $i \neq j$

Comment: Hi Ben this is true yes. Thank you for the comment